# Tkinter pack not resizing frame embedded in canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make scrollable frame in Tkinter that prompts the user to type something, which then adds the phrase and a new row upon pressing Enter. For some reason, the frame within the canvas doesn't seem to be resizing after adding 4 rows, even though I'm using pack to add the new row. I tried adding a height parameter to the row Frames, but it didn't seem to change anything. Is there a problem with how I'm configuring the scroll bar?

```
import tkinter as tk

class TermDisplayFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=100, height=50):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window = self.frame, anchor=tk.NW, tags='frame')

        self.canvas.pack(side='left')
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self,orient='vertical')  
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.pack(side='right',fill='y')
        self.scroll.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.onCanvasConfigure(e, self.canvas))

        self.initialize_header()
        self.initialize_entry()

    def onCanvasConfigure(self,e, widget):
        self.canvas.itemconfig('frame', height=self.canvas.winfo_height(), width=self.canvas.winfo_width())
        print('Configure triggered')


    def reset_scroll_region(self,event=False):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

    def initialize_header(self):
        row = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        tk.Label(row, width=5, text='Term', borderwidth='2', relief='groove').pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        tk.Label(row, width=5, text='Meaning', borderwidth='2', relief='groove').pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        tk.Label(row, width=5, text='Apply to\n\n', borderwidth='2', relief='groove').pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        tk.Label(row, width=5, text='Times', borderwidth='2', relief='groove').pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        row.pack(side='top', fill='x')

    def initialize_entry(self):
        self.recent_row = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.recent_row, width=5, borderwidth='2', relief='groove')
        self.entry.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        tk.Label(self.recent_row, width=5, text='replaced by', borderwidth='2', relief='groove').pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        tk.Label(self.recent_row, width=5, text='Apply to\n\n', borderwidth='2', relief='groove').pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        tk.Label(self.recent_row, width=5, text='Times', borderwidth='2', relief='groove').pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        self.recent_row.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.add_row)

    def add_row(self, event):
        text = self.entry.get()
        self.entry.forget()
        tk.Label(self.recent_row, width=5, text=text, borderwidth='2', relief='groove').pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        self.initialize_entry()
        self.reset_scroll_region()
        print(self.frame.winfo_children())
        print(self.frame.winfo_height())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    TermDisplayFrame(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

- `self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)` should be `self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)` instead
- you have reset the frame height inside `onCanvasConfigure()`.  Change `self.canvas.itemconfig('frame', height=self.canvas.winfo_height(), width=self.canvas.winfo_width())` to `self.canvas.itemconfig('frame', width=self.canvas.winfo_width())` instead
- you need to call `self.frame.update_idletasks()` to update the frame before calling `self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))` inside `reset_scroll_region()`